# Flush old entries from nftable meter list

Tags: rate-limiting, nftables

I use nftables to do rate limiting:

```
chain input: {
    type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
    tcp dport http ct state new jump rate-limit
}

chain rate-limit {
    meter httplimit4 { ip saddr limit rate 2/second burst 20 packets } counter accept
    drop
}
```

It works, until the list is full. For some reason, once an ip was seen, it stays in the list, even after the rate limiting has "recovered". How can I flush out old entries from the list?

Of course I could run a cron job with

```
nft flush meter inet filter httplimit4
```

periodically, but isn't there some way to tell nftables to drop entries from the table when the ip was not seen for some time?